# Windows universal application (WIN 10) app manifest validation error

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, appxmanifest

I found error in Blank app (Windows Universal) template in Visual Studio 2015 RC.

It is some mismatch inside schemas.

> error 0xC00CE014: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must
>   be valid as per schema: Line 23, Column 4, Reason: Element
>   '{http:/schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}TargetDeviceFamily'
>   is unexpected according to content model of parent element
>   '{http:/schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Dependencies'.
>   Expecting:
>   {http:/schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}TargetPlatform.

Package.appxmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">

  <Identity
    Name="a29f94a4-dc5e-4558-9497-90c6190f49ef"
    Publisher="CN=Petr"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="a29f94a4-dc5e-4558-9497-90c6190f49ef" 
                    PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>App1</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Petr</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal"
                        MinVersion="10.0.10069.0"
                        MaxVersionTested="10.0.10069.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="App1.App">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="App1"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png"
        Description="App1"
        BackgroundColor="#464646">
        <!--ForegroundText="dark"-->
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: You have to re-create the manifest....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting this error when deploying the app to your Windows system, it means that you are trying to deploy/install the app package on an older Windows 10 Preview system. Please ensure that you have the Windows 10 version that was publicly announced at //Build.

http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/04/29/new-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10074-now-available/